# using enum list as parameter in HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, persistence, hql

I have an entity called `Band` with a attribute `List<Genres> genres`, Genres is a ENUM with the following values: `ALTERNATIVE_ROCK("Alternative Rock"), CLASSIC_ROCK("Classic Rock"), HARD_ROCK("Hard Rock"), HEAVY_METAL("Heavy Metal"),PROGRESSIVE_ROCK("Progressive Rock");`

I'm trying to create a method that returns a `List<Band>` using an `List<Genres>` as parameter using HQL, something like:

```
public List<Band> listBandsPerGenres(List<Genres> genres);
```

But i'm receiving some errors with HQL queries that i'd tried?

Above some hql queries that i've tried...

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("SELECT b FROM Band b JOIN FETCH b.genres g WHERE g IN (?)");
        q.setParameter(0, genres);
        return q.list();
```

returns an error saying that an ArrayList cannot be cast to Enum...

or...

```
"SELECT b FROM Band b JOIN FETCH b.genres g WHERE g.value IN (?)"
```

returns an error like :  dereference scalar collection element ENUM

property genres mapping, entity Band...

```
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Genres.class)
    @CollectionTable(name="banda_generos", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_banda", nullable=false))
    private List<Genres> genres;
```

Comment: what were those queries you tried, and what were the corresponding errors?

Comment: Please add the annotations of the `List<Genres>`, it's important to see if it is `EnumType.String` or the default.

Comment: i'm using this ENUM like ENUMTYPE.STRING

Comment: Please add the entire property with all the annotations (the genre property)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for Hibernate 4

```
    Query q = s
            .createQuery("SELECT b FROM Q27715453$Band b JOIN b.genres g WHERE g IN (:genres)");
    q.setParameterList("genres", Arrays.asList(Genres.ROCK, Genres.CLASSIC));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q.list().toArray()));
```

Check that the method `Query#setParameterList` is used instead of `Query#setParameter`, also it's used `g` insted of `g.value`.

Comment: thanks!!! it worked perfectly!!! Happy new year and keep on rocking with Java uahauhauhauhauah !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. According to [JPA spec (section 4.6.9. page 185)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) lists aren't supported as left-side operand with `IN` expression.

Comment: like @AVolpe said in the answer below... it works with Hibernate 4 with using setParameterList method