# Can't pass in List of Enums into Hibernate Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql

I am trying to pass in a list of enums into my hibernate query. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public Integer getReportRunsCount(Set<ReportRunStatus> statusSet, Optional<String> userId) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(1) from ReportRun r where r.status in (:fieldStatuses) and r.createdBy = :userId");
    query.setParameterList("fieldStatuses", Arrays.asList(statusSet));
    query.setString("userId", userId.orElse(null));
    return Ints.checkedCast((Long)query.uniqueResult());
}
```

ReportRunStatus.java:

```
public enum ReportRunStatus {
    STARTED,
    QUERYDATA,
    PROCESSINGDATA,
    COMPLETED,
    CANCELLED,
    ERROR;
}
```

I am just trying to pass in these `fieldStatuses` as a parameter where `ReportRunStatus` is a class of enums. However, I keep getting this error saying that

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum`

Any ideas why this might happen? I Looked at this link here: [using enum list as parameter in HQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715453/using-enum-list-as-parameter-in-hql-query) as reference to do what I am trying to do but I keep getting the error above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What is causing problem is this one: `Arrays.asList(statusSet)`

This is simply creating a one-element list, with a `Set` as the value (i.e. a `List<Set<ReportRunStatus>>`. However `setParameterList` is expecting a `Collection<ReportRunStatus>`, hence it caused class cast exception because internally it was getting an element out (which is a `HashSet<ReportRunStatus>`) and trying to cast it to a `ReportRunStatus`.

What you should do is something like

```
query.setParameterList("fieldStatuses", statusSet);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 List<String> reportRunStatusList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(ReportRunStatus reportRunStatus : statusSet){
     reportRunStatusList.add(reportRunStatus.toString);
 }
 query.setParameterList("fieldStatuses", reportRunStatusList);
```

You just needed to convert the enums to String explicitly.

Comment: No you don't need to convert it to String, given the mapping is correct done against an enum